# Asserting Array objects in JSonPath with key

Tags: junit, jsonpath, mockmvc

I'm trying to get a specific array item not by the array position, but by the content key.

Example JSON:

```
{"items": [{
        "key": "prop-name",
        "label": "Provider",
        "type": "DROPDOWN",
        "items": ["bla", "blub", "what", "ever"]
    }, {
        "key": "prop-modes",
        "label": "Transport modes",
        "type": "CHECKBOX",
        "items": ["AIR", "RAIL", "ROAD", "SEA"]
    }
]}
```

```java
private static String URL_GLOBAL_FILTER = "/global-filter";
private static String PROP_NAME = "prop-name";

mvc.perform(get(URL_GLOBAL_FILTER).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(status().isOk())
   .andExpect(jsonPath("$.items", hasSize(10)))
   .andExpect(jsonPath("$.items[?((@.key === \"" + PROP_NAME + "\" && @.type === \"DROPDOWN\"))]").exists())
   .andExpect(jsonPath("$.items[0].items", hasSize(4)));
```

This works perfectly fine. But what I want to do is something like:

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.items[?(@.key == \"prop-name\")].items", containsString("bla")))
```

But that throws the following error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$.items[?(@.key == "prop-name")].items"
```

Expected: a string containing "bla"
     but: was a net.minidev.json.JSONArray (<[["bla","blub","what","ever"]]>)

What does the `< >` mean? How to access the array inside?

In [jsonQueryTool](http://www.jsonquerytool.com/#/JSONPath) it seems to be what I want.

(UPDATED question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the `hasItem` matcher from Hamcrest?

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;

.andExpect(jsonPath("$.items[?(@.key == 'prop-name')].items[*]", hasItem("bla")));
```

Comment: `*` is a wildcard, `items[*]` means selecting all elements of the items array